# Combine "replace" and wildcards in SQL query

Tags: mysql

Within a table like this:

```
ID| ph_number
-----------
1 | 51231234
2 | 5123 1234
3 | 51231234; 61231234
4 | 5123 1234; 61231234
5 | 5123 1934; 6123 1234
6 | 5123 1234; 6123 1234
7 | aargh; 5123 1234; 6123 1234
```

, user needs to find a phone number (ex 51231234) not knowing where the spaces are, or if there are many numbers per field. I can find the numbers without spaces with query like this:

```
SELECT ID, ph_number FROM test WHERE REPLACE(ph_number, ' ', '') LIKE REPLACE('51231234', ' ', '')
```

that returns IDs 1 and 2, or

```
SELECT ID, ph_number FROM test WHERE ph_number LIKE '%51231234%'
```

that returns IDs 1 and 3. But Needed are IDs 1,2,3,4, 6 and 7. I'm not able to combine the two queries. Have tried:

```
SELECT ID, ph_number FROM test WHERE REPLACE(ph_number, ' ', '') LIKE ('%' + REPLACE('51231234', ' ', '') + '%') // returns 1 & 2
SELECT ID, ph_number FROM test WHERE REPLACE(ph_number, ' ', '') LIKE '%' + REPLACE('51231234', ' ', '') + '%' // returns ERROR
```

How could I achieve this? I wouldn't want to tell users that they can't have multiple numbers on the field.

Comment: May be you want to use `concat()` to concatenate strings? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18ff4/4/0

Comment: oh.. yes, that does the trick, thanks! Put it in an answer please :)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question

Comment: Not a good habit, plus it was your answer, not mine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL "+" is exclusively an arithmetic operator. Use the `CONCAT()` function to concatenate strings:

```
....WHERE REPLACE(ph_number, ' ', '') LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('51231234', ' ', ''), '%')
```